# Polynomials that share at least one root

Tags: geometry, polynomials, roots, plane-geometry

Let $P(x) = x^2 + Bx + C$, for $B,C \in \mathbb{R}$, have real roots.
Represent the set of all other $p(x)= x^2 + bx + c$ that share a root with $P(x)$ by a plot in the $bc$-plane. It forms a nice picture:
for example, here it is for $B=3, C=-1$, when 
the roots are $-\frac{1}{2}
   \left(3 \pm \sqrt{13}\right)$:

---

[image: RootSharing]

          

<sup>Lines intersect at $b=3,c=-1$.</sup>

---

All those $(b,c)$ on the two lines share a root with 
$x^2 + 3x -1$. The lines are tangent to the paraboloid
$b^2 = 4c$, where the discriminant is zero.
Two questions:

> ***Q1***. Can you explain the characteristics of this picture
>   geometrically, without relying heavily on explicit algebraic calculations?

By "the characteristics" I mean: Two straight lines meeting
at the $B,C$ point, tangent to the discriminant parabola.

> ***Q2***. What is the analogous picture for $P(x) = x^3 + B x^2 + C x + D$, the set of cubic polynomials that share at least one root
>   with $P(x)$, plotted in $bcd$-space?

I would welcome further generalizations: To coefficients and
roots in $\mathbb{C}$, and/or to higher degree polynomials.

Comment: Nice question, +1.

Comment: I am not sure about the parabolic description - for a given $a$ results a linear relation between $b$ and $c$. $(x-a)(x-y)=0$ leads (by eliminating $y$) to the relation between the $b$ and $c$

Comment: For the Qubed one take the same process - for a solution $a$ (real number?) you derive a relation between B, C, D by eliminating the other two roots.

Comment: With regard to the Qube - you get a plane

Comment: Generalized question posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335232/polynomials-that-share-at-least-one-root

Comment: And [answered on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/335241/6094).

Answer (score 1):

Fix a root $\alpha$ of $P(X)$.
Then every polynomial of that form with root $\alpha$ must be of the form $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ and $b=-\alpha-\beta, c=\alpha\beta$.
From this formula we get that the dependance between $c$ and $b$ is linear.
More specifically $c=-\alpha b-\alpha^2$.
This way you obtain a line through $(B,C)$ and if you chose the other root you obtain the other line.

Now, about the parabola, it is clear that these lines must intersect it in the point $(-2\alpha_1,\alpha_1^2 )$ and $(-2\alpha_2,\alpha_2^2)$ and they certainly can't go in the $b^2<4c$ area because a point in this zone corresponds to a polynomial with no real root.
It follows that the lines must be tangent to the parabola.

Comment: Nice, but I don't see the tangencies at $(\alpha_i,\alpha_i)$. In my example, the two roots are $-3.303$ and $0.303$, whereas one tangency is about $(10,6.3)$.

Comment: You are right, I meant the point corresponding to the roots $(\alpha_1,\alpha_1)$ which is $(-2\alpha_1,\alpha_1^2)$

Comment: $(-2 \alpha_1, \alpha_1^2) \approx (6.6,10.9)$---checks out.